# how to display two home pages for two different users using php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

i'm new for web developing and i have a question regarding user login. I have two types of users and I need to link them for two different home pages when they log in. for an example the user whose user id is M00001 should get the home page MemberHome.php and the user whose user id is G00001 should get the home page called GuestHome.php. 
Please tell me how should i create my web pages according to above requirement using PHP and MySql.

Comment: Put a field in your user database that says whether they're a member or guest. The login script looks them up in the table, finds the user type, and then sends a redirect to the appropriate page.

Comment: thanks...got your idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In database fields probably you can store a field call 'user_type' 
'user_type' field contains 'member', 'guest', etc.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use template for each user's role? try this:

```
<?php
/*I assumed that you already have the variables which retrieved from MYSQL and saved it in $role */
if($role == 'M00001' ){
  include 'MemberHome.php';
}else if($role == 'G00001'}{
  include 'GuestHome.php';
}
?>
```

But I suggest that you should use some framework like Laravel or Yii to easily maintain and help you very much in routing

Comment: You can also use an `array` as a look-up table to avoid a lot of unnecessary `if` statements.

Comment: thanks duong khang

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer @lanlee and don't hesitate if you have any question